# Asp.net MVC routing using subfolders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m trying to use subfolders within the Controllers folder:

The structure looks like this:

- Controllers (Folder)

  - LoginController.cs
  - WelcomeController.cs
  - Settings (Folder)

    - UsersController.cs

I've several problems.
When I perform a return RedirectToAction("Index", "welcome") from my LoginController, the url looks like http://mywebsite.local/settings/welcome
I thought I will get a 404 error..

How to make the redirection launches http://mywebsite.local/welcome and get a 404 error when I launch http://mywebsite.local/settings/welcome

Do I really need to use Areas?

This is my RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "settings",
            url: "settings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );            

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder structure of your controllers here has very little relevance to what you are seeing. You could maintain that structure and accomplish your goal if the route would work.

However, you've specified two matching routes that can be used to encode the same action, and it is simply giving the first one priority. See, routes don't just work forwards, MVC uses them in reverse, too, to process your `____Action()` statements. You could specify a named route (e.g. "settings") in your `RedirectToAction("Index", "welcome")`, by using `RedirectToRoute` instead, or manually specify all the routes that have prefixes in your route table. but why start your project off with intentionally conflicting routes like this?

As Joe R said, Areas will make your life easier. Why? Mainly because there is an additional built-in route parameter to do exactly what you want. Really, the question becomes "why avoid Areas?"

Answer (score 7):

> Do I really need to use Areas?

No, but you're trying to re-invent the wheel - creating a structure a bit like Areas. I'd recommend you go with Areas, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

**Area Hype:**
I wouldn't recommend applying Areas *just* because you can.
That would be like "*giving a man a hammer and suddenly everything's a nail*".
In this case we have a cool feature called "*Areas*" and (without knowing the underlying architecture)
    others recommended it the instant someone asks about sub-folders.
Areas weren't designed for the sole purpose of giving you an extra Route Parameter.
The "Areas" original intent is to give you a clear SoC (Separation of Concerns).

**For Example:**
Say you have two separate web application experiences and have decided to roll them under one Solution.
Your call-center may need to look up detailed information and enter in data on individual customers,
    while your managers and executives will peruse higher-level reporting and rarely enter in data.
In this scenario it may make sense to split your business logic into "*Reporting*" and "*CallCenter*" Areas.

**Sub-Directories:**
In MVC, the Sub-Folders you use under "*Controllers*" are Ignored when it comes to Routing.
SubFolders are perfectly fine with how the Questioner is using them to organize his Controllers.
Adding a SubFolder name to his URL makes for a more human-readable URL too.
He just made a mistake in the exclusivity of his first Mapping Route.
The problem is it was matching on *everything*.
Just because you have "*settings/*" in your MapRoute doesn't mean it will apply only to incoming URL's.
MVC will use your MapRoute Logic to figure how you would like to write your URL's too!

**The Fix (Option 1 - Use MapRoute):**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Settings",
    url: "Settings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },//Remove the Default Controller as we want to explicitly require it and constrain it. - 08/26/2018 - MCR.
    constraints: new { controller = "Users|Admins" }//If you have other Controllers under a SubFolder (say we also had AdminsController.cs), then simply Pipe-Delimit them. - 08/26/2018 - MCR.
);
```

This is the way I've chosen to go, but if you want tighter control, you could use the Option below instead.

**The Fix (Option 2 - Use Route-Attributes):**
First, make sure you enable this feature by adding `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();//Add this BEFORE MapRoute for Route-Attributes to work.
```

Next, Decorate your Controller with the following Attributes:
    (You may even include Default/Optional Values, just like in your MapRoute.)

```
[RoutePrefix("Settings/Users")]//Add your ParentFolder and Include your Controller name too.
[Route("{action=Index}/{id?}")]//You need this if you are using the RoutePrefix Attribute.  Without this, you will need to define "[Route]" above every Action-Method. - 08/26/2018 - MCR.
public class UsersController : Controller
```

**Note**:
If you use Route-Attributes instead of MapRoute, then you will *not* be able to hit the
    Controller without the "*Settings*" Prefix.
With the Custom and Default MapRoutes, you could have accessed your controller either way.
By decorating your Controller with these Attributes, you now *force* it to only use this exact path.
This may be what you want, but if you start IIS Express from Visual Studio on one of your Views,
    then it will not find it because Visual Studio does not know to add the RoutePrefix for you.
I say this, so you are not discouraged when you start debugging and think it doesn't work.

See this link for more information about Attribute-Routing:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer not answering the question, because IMHO, we use `Area` when we need mini program under our main program,

ie. Forum, (Comprehensive) Blog, Marketplace (under our main site) either forum.mainsite.com or mainsite.com/forum

> So you DONT need `Area` in your case

**Solutions :**

FYI, routing are something that have nothing to do with your architecture / structure / foldering in your applications.

**In Example** your ControllerName is `SettingsUsersController`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "settings",
    url: "settings/users/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SettingsUsers", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**in your case**, you can fix your routing like this (this is for making sure you have `pretty url` but still simple Controller structure):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "settings",
    url: "settings/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SettingsUsers", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

> Your ControllerName would be `SettingsUsersController`

**SettingsUsersController.cs**

```
public class SettingsUsersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/SettingsUsers/Index.cshtml", db.YourDBName.ToList());
    }
}
```

And why `404`? I think because you are not "routing" correctly your `View`, you should do make subfolder like this under your Views Folder `Views/SettingsUsers/Index.cshtml`